# Enviar dados de input para outra página em React

Tags: react

Olá!

Estou estudando ReactJs e fazendo um pequeno projeto onde tenho uma página que preciso preencher alguns inputs e ao clicar no botão "Gerar" redirecionar para outra página mostrando esses dados, é possível fazer isso apenas com o React?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {

    const [nome, setNome] = useState("")
    const [cpf, setCpf] = useState("")

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="container">
                <form className="form">
                    <div className="boxDados">
                        <div className="boxTitulo">
                            <h2>Dados do Representante</h2>
                            <p>Preencha os campos abaixo com os dados do representante</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="boxInputs">
                            <label>
                                <span>Nome:</span>
                                <input type="text" name="nome" required onChange={(e) => setNome(e.target.value)} value={nome} />
                            </label>
                            <label>
                                <span>CPF:</span>
                                <input type="text" name="cpf" required onChange={(e) => setCpf(e.target.value)} value={cpf} />
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="dadosNovaPagina">
                        <strong>As informações abaixo gostaria de mostrar em uma nova página quando o usuario clicar no botão GERAR</strong>
                        <p>Seu nome é: {nome}</p>
                        <p>Seu CPF é: {cpf}</p>
                    </div>

                    <button>Gerar</button>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: O react é feito para você basicamemente NÃO fazer isso (redirecionar para outra página) – pode até mudar a url, mas com react geralmente toda a tela é atualizada sem recarregar a janela a partir do servidor.

Answer (score -4):

Opa amigo, há várias formas de fazer isso usando o React, vou citar duas!

Você pode passar parâmetros pelo state do Link no ReactRouterDOM

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
...
<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />
```

> docs: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state

Após passar o parâmetro você pode pegar ele usando o hook useLocation(), seus parâmtros vão estar dentro da variável location

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  ...
  ...
}
```

> doc: https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location#locationstate

talvez o framework tanstack possa te ajudar também,
esse vídeo aqui explica como ele funciona, espero que te ajude!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q-206WRzOHQ&ab_channel=Rocketseat